# Waitresource format explanation in deadlock xml

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a deadlock xml where two transactions are deadlocked on two resources. waitresource attributes of the process elements have values "OBJECT: 8:1269579561:4" and "OBJECT: 8:1269579561:0".

It looks like table objects locks but what are the third parts in the object description: ":4" and ":0"? Where can I find detailed explanation of the waitresource attribute?

Comment: This will help https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106772/8783.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [Lock Partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2014#lock-partitioning)

> For large computer systems, locks on frequently referenced objects can
>   become a performance bottleneck as acquiring and releasing locks place
>   contention on internal locking resources. Lock partitioning enhances
>   locking performance by splitting a single lock resource into multiple
>   lock resources. This feature is only available for systems with 16 or
>   more CPUs, and is automatically enabled and cannot be disabled. Only
>   object locks can be partitioned.

You can see this by comparing the deadlock message in the errorlog with the deadlock xml in the system_health XEvents session, which you can query like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(xml, event_data).query('/event/data/value/child::*') AS DeadlockReport,
    timestamp_utc, datediff(s,timestamp_utc,GETUTCDATE()) sec_ago
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(
        cast(SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName') as varchar(max)) + 
        '\..\system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
WHERE OBJECT_NAME like 'xml_deadlock_report';
```

From the errorlog:

```
 Message OBJECT: 2:1013578649:15        CleanCnt:2 Mode:IS Flags: 0x1
```

from the deadlock xml:

```
 <objectlock lockPartition="15" objid="1013578649"
```

Comment: I thought so but then found similar thread here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb574c87-dd6d-46fe-9951-04ef17f61867/could-sql-server-lock-partitioning-cause-deadlock?forum=transactsql so now not sure

Comment: Since it was Kalen Delaney who didn't think it was the lock partition, I provisioned a 16 core VM in Azure and tested by generating a IS/Sch-M deadlock.  It is.

Comment: That thread has a lot of misinformation then yes? The accepted answer and the previous accepted answer on the msdn link both are apparently incorrect.

Comment: Yep.  I added another answer there.